# Need to add string in Oracle

Tags: sql, regex, string, oracle, oracle11g

Below is my data in the column.

```
73-11277-61 B0
 68-3038-61 C0
```

Always I need to add ~ before two characters in Oracle.

```
 73-11277-61 ~B0
  68-3038-61 ~C0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If you mean to add before last two characters of the string without
  any extra consideration, then using

  `SUBSTR(value,1,LENGTH(value)-2)||'~'||SUBSTR(value,-2)`

  is enough.
- If you need to add before letter characters within the pattern, then
  use

  `REGEXP_REPLACE(value,'([[:alpha:]])','~\1')`
- If you need to add just after a white space character, then use

  `REGEXP_REPLACE(value,'(\s)',' ~\2')`

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=37bb4703d9c27ab742a1a781baed4d18)</kbd>